# Can women in niddah dance and hold a sefer Torah on Simkhat Torah?

Tags: halacha, women, sefer-torah, simchat-torah

Is there any opinion that allows women in niddah to dance holding the **sefer Torah** on *Simkhat Torah*?

Comment: I once saw an igros Moshe. He discouages all women from holding the Sefer Torah because of this concern.

Answer (score 7):

There is a Rambam ([Laws of Sefer Torah 10:8](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Tefillin,_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.10.8?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) based on [Berakhot 22a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.22a.8?with=all&lang=bi)) which explicitly permits *niddot* to touch a sefer Torah

> Any impure person, even [a woman in] a niddah state or a gentile, may
>   hold a Torah scroll and read it.

[SA YD 282:9](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.282.9?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) rules the same

Some  poskim disagree based on minhag, e.g., [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=1920) but see the end of [R Weiss article](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%2020/No.%202/Women%20And%20Sifrei.pdf) showing many Acharonim write this minhag has no basis.

PS. I assume you are not speaking of mixed dancing which will have its own set of prohibitions.

Answer (score 2):

Q: Chacham Ovadia Mayaan Omer 3: pg.202 was asked a question coming from outside Eretz Yisroel. The question was can women dance with the sefer Torah?

A: Chacham Ovadia answered that they should not do so. They then proceeded to ask does the halacha change if they dance with sifrei nach on klaf, or if the women 
dance by themselves privately? Chacham Ovadia answered it’s not proper, but added if the men would not see the women at all then it is possible, but the look on his face 
showed he wasn’t happy with the idea.

In the footnotes ,it's explained that this was not a halachic consideration ,since it is permitted for a woman to hold a Torah even while being a niddah, but is more of a hashkafic reason as mentioned in the footnotes ,that this was never the custom and seems to be coming from not pure motivations (equality).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89198/discussion-on-answer-by-sam-can-women-in-niddah-dance-and-hold-a-sefer-torah-on).